# В многоуровневом меню 3-ий уровень сделать под 2-ым

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, меню

Я уже сделал выпадение 3-ого уровня сразу же под li, используя top:0;, где содержится еще подменю, но он идет поверху(ведь я задал z-index выше), но совершенно не пойму как сделать и также не смог нагуглить так, чтобы и пункты 2-ого уровня оставались видимыми сразу же под 3-им уровнем. Прошу помощи с этим вопросом.

[Вот мои наработки](https://jsfiddle.net/1e2yof2x/)

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.menu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  background: #404853;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #a3b0c1;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background: #e5526f;
  color: white;
}

.menu ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 220px;
  left: 0;
}

.menu li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul ul {
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="active"><span>дизайн</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">страницы</a>
        <ul class="sub_m">
          <li><a href="#">Об авторе</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Редакторы</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Главный копирайтер</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Участники</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Расписание</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Идет набор</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">О сайте</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Для пользователей</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Наши работы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Статьи</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Связь</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Вот, что у меня не получается сделать[(картинка)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skaiu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если на css то как-то так, чтоб меню плавно появлялось, можна hover через JS написать

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.menu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  max-width:140px;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  background: #404853;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #a3b0c1;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background: #e5526f;
  color: white;
}

.menu ul {
  opacity: 0;
  display:none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  top: 100%;
  width: 220px;
  left: 0;
}

.menu li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  display:block;
}
.sub_m li ul li a{
background:blue;
}

.menu ul ul {
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="active"><span>дизайн</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">страницы</a>
        <ul class="sub_m">
          <li><a href="#">Об авторе</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Редакторы</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Главный копирайтер</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Участники</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Расписание</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Идет набор</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">О сайте</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Для пользователей</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Наши работы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Статьи</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Связь</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот, что у меня не получается сделать http://joxi.ru/MAjqN9PCvGMBD2

Comment: немного изменив стили, удалили position:absolute;

Comment: На практике, такая конструкция может работать только с JS и открытием выпадающих пунктов по клику на стрелку. В противном случае, мы будем ловить постоянные "скачки", если рядом будут находится 2 пункта с вложенными списками. То есть, после открытия первого списка, будем переводить ниже на следующий пункт и когда первый закроется, все "подпрыгнет" вверх.